# Writing function to find longest path through list (recursion maybe?)

Tags: python

I have a sorted list of up to 50 items as so:
[50,120,160,180,190,250,260,280,300,400,410,475]

and I have legal possible 'spaces' in another list (about 20):
[30, 60, 70]

basically I'm trying to figure out the longest line possible using those spaces as the allowed amount between each value

That is in this case, we'd have
50,120,180,250,280
as our longest line (5 items).

Comment: So, if I'm reading this right, that's starting at `50`, then `+70`, `+60`, `+70`, `+30`?

Comment: That's correct, but it could be any (+30, +60, +70) so long as it leads to the longest option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remembering for each item a longest path ending with that item:

```
>>> p = {}
>>> for i in items:
        p[i] = max((p.get(i - s, []) for s in spaces), key=len) + [i]

>>> max(p.values(), key=len)
[50, 120, 190, 250, 280]
```

Comment: I think this works. I'm testing it now in a few other cases, but it looks like it works. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe add a few sentences of explanation? This is a nice solution, but it's bit cryptic.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully I understood from your example:

```py
base_list = [50,120,160,180,190,250,260,280,300,400,410,475]
spaces = [30, 60, 70]

def calculate(base):
    for i,x in enumerate(base):
        if 0 == i or (base[i] - base[i-1]) in spaces:
            continue
        else:
            del base[i]
            return calculate(base)

    return base

print( calculate(base_list[:]) )
```

Comment: You probably shouldn't be modifying the input list, and you also shouldn't modify a list while iterating over it. Also, your solution only finds _a_ subsequence with the given spacing, not the longest. For `[0, 30, 50, 120]` (and the same spaces as the example), the answer should be `[0, 50, 120]`, but your code gives `[0, 30]`.

Comment: It doesn't work for other examples but thanks for trying.
I think it might have to be done recursively, but I've been having trouble wrapping my head around how to do it that way.

Answer (score 1):

One possible naive solution would be to iterate over the list, keeping a list of every possible subsequence that fits the requirement.

```py
def longest_spaced_subsequence(values, spaces):
    candidates = []
    for element in values:
        # look at each of the subsequences
        for i in range(len(candidates)):
            candidate = candidates[i]

            # if the new element has good spacing from
            # the highest in the candidate, add it.
            if element - candidate[-1] in spaces:
                # make a copy and and add the element to it
                new = list(candidate)
                new.append(element)
                candidates.append(new)

        # maybe this element is the start of the longest sequence
        candidates.append([element])

    return max(candidates, key=len)
```

This is far from the most efficient algorithm, but it works.

There is one area where this naive algorithm really needs improvement: it keeps all of the candidate lists forever, so it takes up far more memory than it needs to. To save memory, you just need to remove short candidates that can't be extended any more, which is only a little trickier than it sounds.

As you guessed in the question title, recursion could help with this problem as well. You could take a greedy approach a bit more like [Samuel Elh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60178257), but instead of just returning the result, you have to keep going and make sure that it's really the longest.

Comment: Thanks, I think this one works as well. Really well explained too, thanks a ton.

Comment: It's indeed not exactly efficient. For example `longest_spaced_subsequence(range(30), [1, 2])` already builds up 5.7 million candidates and takes several seconds to run.